# SP 2013 - Modify template for document library

Tags: 2013, list-template

I've just taken over as Site Collection Admin for a site that regularly needs new document libraries created. A document library template was developed for creating these libraries. The business users have requested changes to the template.

How do I modify the template? I know how to create a new template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really. You need to create a new library off of the existing template, make the desired changes, then create a new template off of that. Then you can provision new libraries off the new template.